# Ubuntu 20.04 - networking down after reboot - netplan config issue?

Tags: networking, 20.04, netplan

I have a server with a bonded interface. Here is the netplan file:

```
# cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
   enp1s0f0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: []
      optional: true
   enp1s0f1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: []
      optional: true
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [enp1s0f0, enp1s0f1]
      optional: true
      addresses:
      - 10.10.10.150/29
      gateway4: 10.10.10.145
      nameservers:
          addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
      parameters:
          lacp-rate: fast
          mii-monitor-interval: 100
          mode: 802.3ad
          transmit-hash-policy: layer2+3
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

Everything works fine and my server gets the address listed (10.10.10.150).

I need to add additional addresses, so I have created the following file:

```
# cat /etc/netplan/60.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  bonds:
    bond0:
      addresses:
        - 10.10.11.0/24
        - 10.10.11.1/24
```

If I run netplan apply everything works without issue. If I reboot, I am unable to access the server. If I KVM into it and run netplan apply everything magically works again.

Quick look at journalctl and I see the following:

```
# journalctl --no-pager -lu systemd-networkd
-- Logs begin at Sun 2021-10-31 02:26:37 UTC, end at Sun 2021-10-31 02:28:05 UTC. --
Oct 31 02:26:38 res-d035 systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Oct 31 02:26:38 res-d035 systemd-networkd[461]: bond0: netdev ready
Oct 31 02:26:38 res-d035 systemd-networkd[461]: Enumeration completed
Oct 31 02:26:38 res-d035 systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Oct 31 02:26:38 res-d035 systemd-networkd[461]: enp1s0f1: Link UP
Oct 31 02:26:38 res-d035 systemd-networkd[461]: enp1s0f0: Link UP
Oct 31 02:26:38 res-d035 systemd-networkd[461]: bond0: IPv6 successfully enabled
Oct 31 02:26:38 res-d035 systemd-networkd[461]: bond0: Link UP
Oct 31 02:26:41 res-d035 systemd-networkd[461]: enp1s0f1: Gained carrier
Oct 31 02:26:41 res-d035 systemd-networkd[461]: bond0: Gained carrier
Oct 31 02:26:41 res-d035 systemd-networkd[461]: enp1s0f0: Gained carrier
Oct 31 02:26:42 res-d035 systemd-networkd[461]: bond0: Gained IPv6LL
Oct 31 02:27:03 res-d035 systemd-networkd[461]: bond0: Could not set address: Connection timed out
Oct 31 02:27:03 res-d035 systemd-networkd[461]: bond0: Failed
```

The last two lines are my error, and do NOT exist when I reboot without the 60.yaml file.

What am I doing wrong here? I assume something is not setup correctly in the 60.yaml file, I just can't figure out where I am messing it up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did NOT find a solution.  Reverted to just running through rc.local with `ip addr add` commands for now.  Thanks to everyone that attempted to assist.

Comment: Is this a  solarflare card? Try to do a `onload_tool reload` to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although i don't have any experience with netplan; But the problem seems to me in 10.10.11.0/24, Don't assign **NETWORK ID 10.10.11.0/24**  change the **0** to something else.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I tried removing that entry (10.10.11.0/24) from the 60.yaml file and I experience the same issue; no network on boot.  Again, I appreciate the response.

Comment: Ok, As reviewed once again, you are assigning bond0 IP twice once in 01-netcfg.yaml file and second time in 60.yaml, To use second IP addresses also you need to create VLANs for that and then attach it to bond0.

Comment: Is there another way to assign the second ip address?  I was under the impression the way I was assigning it in these files would append the addresses - and it works, it just doesn't work on a reboot.  The only reason I'm doing it in this second file is because the first file is managed by the hosting provider and can be overwritten at any time.

Comment: It wont be a problem, just create VLANs in different file and attached to bond0. As you doing in 60.yml

Comment: You do not have to create vlans to assign multiple addresses to an interface.  You should only assign addresses to vlans if your network is configured with vlans.

Comment: I don't know an answer to the original problem being reported, but vlans are not it.  I would suggest checking if the problem is reproducible if you put all the configuration for the network interface into a single file instead of splitting it.

Comment: that is  correct that we can assign different IP addresses to one interface no doubt about it as i saw seperated files then suggested vlans for it. @10 I think he is right once put the addresses in same file that might solved the issue

Comment: @slangasek - Thanks for the response!  I moved the address all to the same file (01-netcfg.yaml) and it does produce the same error.   No solution there.